# Make clock auto refresh

Tags: javascript, time

How do I make my clock auto refresh, because it only shows the time the page was loaded?

```js
(function time () {
    document.write(new Date().toString("hh:mm:ss tt"));
})();
```

Comment: Just a minor tip...do not use `document.write`...is the devil itself!!

Comment: Use `setInterval`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach requires, say, `<div id="txt"></div>` in your html template:

```
var timer = document.getElementById('timer');

function startTime() {
var today = new Date();
var h = today.getHours();
var m = today.getMinutes();
var s = today.getSeconds();
var ampm = h >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
h = h % 12;
h = h ? h : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
m = checkTime(m);
s = checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + ampm;
var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
return i;
}

<body onload="startTime()">
```

See also [How to format a javascript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date).
And [here is the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/an7tesgv/).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) or [`window.setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). You have to update the time every seconds (*1000 ms*).

#### setTimeout

```js
(function time () {
 document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = new Date().toString("hh:mm:ss tt");
        var timeout = setTimeout(time, 1000); // recalls the function after 1000 ms
})();
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

#### setInterval

```js
function time () {
 document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = new Date().toString("hh:mm:ss tt");
}
var timeInterval = setInterval(time, 1000); // recalls the function every 1000 ms
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: Will use setinteval. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). This will call your function every `1000`ms

```js
function time() {
  console.log(new Date().toString("hh:mm:ss tt"));
};

setInterval(time, 1000);
```